# Switch widget invisible after checked

Tags: java, android

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Switch change_background;
@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    final LinearLayout 
   background= 
   (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.background);

     change_background= 
   (Switch)findViewById(R.id.switch_button);

   change_background.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
   CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton 
   buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           if(isChecked){

   background.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);

   change_background.setTrackResource(R.color.blue);

   change_background.setThumbResource(R.color.white);   }

    else {


    background.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);

    change_background.setThumbResource(R.color.black);

    change_background.setTrackResource(R.color.blue);

           }
       }
     });}}
```

I used a Linear Layout as the root view of this project ,My intention was to change the background of the app and change the thumb and track of the switch when the switch is checked
and do the same thing with different colors when the switch is unchecked.
But after running the app, when i check the switch widget, the app malfunctions and switch widget goes invisible and nothing works as i intended

note :) Ignore my useless imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setBackgroundColor` takes parameter `@ColorInt` not `@ColorRes` you should change it to

```
 background.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.bg_white));
```